# The best language for photo stitching/VR application

Tags: android, iphone, photo, image-stitching

I'm new to the forum so I am very sorry if I offend any of you with my novice!

I'm 2 months into learning code and I would like to dabble in photo stitching. Similar to iPhone's pano feature or Google Street View.

My easy question is what language is best for me to learn to develop a photo stitching software?

What language is iPhone's pano feature written in? Google Street View?

Thank you so much for the assistance. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Opencv is a very useful and easy to use library for image processing. It is available in c++ python and java so you may chose the language which you are comfortable with and start learning it. Opencv also provides a detailed sample for image stitching.